# ksh error "syntax error at line 5: `(' unexpected"

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I have a php file that print a number, and I want to use this number in my ksh file so I do this but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/sh
testt = $(php /path/to/count.php)
echo $testt
```

I want that the `testt` variable is assigned the number value.

Comment: In ksh, you can use "ttest!= php ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell's tokenizer is white-space sensitive. Use

```
testt=$(php /path/to/count.php)
```

Note: no blanks around `=`.

Comment: The tokenizer isn't really any more or less sensitive to whitespace than any other language's. The problem is that there is no actual assignment statement in shell, only single *words* that are interpreted as assignments when preceding a (possibly empty) command. The `=` alone is *not* sufficient to split a string into multiple words, and in fact an assignment is by definition a single word which *contains* an `=`.